# Can a College of Creation Bard make an instrument play itself?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard, animated-objects

Can a bard of the college of creation use their animating performance class feature to make an instrument play itself?

Comment: Are there any specific benefits you're envisioning from this (beyond cool, presumably)? Having those would let answers more fully help with the problem.

Comment: But where are my manners? Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Maybe with the "Rule of Cool"

According to the rules as written, the [Creation bard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#CollegeofCreation)'s [Animating Performance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#AnimatingPerformance-2997320) feature (TCoE, p. 29) creates a Dancing Item that can dodge, walk, hover, and slam enemies.  None of these would allow it to "play itself."

However, the [artwork introducing the subclass](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/bard#Figure) (on p. 27) clearly shows a Dancing Item which is a humanoid statue that's animated enough to make eye contact with its partner and to move its arms, legs, etc. well enough to dance with her. I therefore believe the answer to this question comes down to your DM's judgement.

In my opinion, most DMs would allow it under "rule of cool" as long as it's not for something ultra-critical that wouldn't be able to be done any other way.

For example, if you want to have your Dancing Item play a particular tune several feet away from you because that's the only way you can think of to release yourself from a trap within the effects of a *Silence* spell, some DMs are likely to disallow it.

However, if you just want to perform a cool duet at a concert, I think most DMs would allow it.